# Extracting the list of resources from the terraform files modified in a GitHub PR

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I want to extract the list of all the resources modified in the Terraform files in a given PR on GitHub. I want to pass this to the "terraform plan/apply" command as targets to limit the scope for the terraform apply command.

e.g. If a .tf file changed is as below in a PR,

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "sandbox" {
...
}


module "sandbox_base" {
  ...
}
```

I would like to extract the resources in all the changed files and pass it to the command as

```
terraform plan -target=kubernetes_namespace.sandbox -target=module.sandbox_base
```

So, I need to extract the list of the targets to pass from the changed .tf files. I have a way to get the list using 2 to 3 tasks in the GitHub action such as getting the list of the changed files in the PR, parsing the list, and passing it on to another task to get the modules changed in the .tf files. However, looking for the script if anyone has one in order not to reinvent the wheel and save time.

Comment: A silly question, but why? Which API is getting rate-limited?

Comment: @MarkoE Changed my wordings and edited the post. Thanks :) It was not related to the rate limit but more to the time taken to refresh the terraform state. This is related to our Clusters in our platform where in one cluster there can be resources deployed by many teams and a specific PR would be applicable to only one app resource. So, specifying the target will limit the scope of the state refresh and apply the infra changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following github actions workflow:

1. it will get all `tf` files that changed
2. extract the name of the resources in each tf
3. pass the list from one job to another through an environment variable exported
4. apply the target changes

**note**: it's not recommended to use `-target`.Use it with caution , you may get an inconsistent state.

```yaml
jobs:
  plan:
    name: Create terraform plan     
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Get all changed tf files
        id: changed-tf-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v38
        with:
          files: |
              **.tf
      - name: get list of tf resources changes
        id: get-tf-resources
        if: steps.changed-tf-files.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        env:
          ALL_CHANGED_FILES: ${{ steps.changed-tf-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
        run: |
          echo "All changed files: $ALL_CHANGED_FILES"
          TF_RESOURCES=$(./scripts/get_tf_resources.sh $ALL_CHANGED_FILES)
          echo "ressources to be planned: $TF_RESOURCES"
          echo TF_RESOURCES=$TF_RESOURCES >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: terraform plan GCP
        if: steps.changed-tf-files.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        uses: dflook/terraform-plan@v1
        with:
            target: ${{ steps.get-tf-resources.outputs.TF_RESOURCES }}
```

As for the parsing script:

```bash
terraform_files=$@

# Extract the resources names from the terraform files

regex="resource \"([a-z0-9_]+)\"\ \"([a-z0-9_-]+)\" \{"
resources=$(grep -Eh "$regex" $terraform_files | sed -E "s/$regex/\1.\2 /g")

#echo $resources
# count number of resources
count=$(echo $resources | wc -w)
#echo "Number of resources: $count"
# Loop through the resources and print them
for resource in $resources; do
    echo "$resource"
done
```

this script only parses `resources`, for your use case, you may add a regex for `modules` also:

```bash
regex_modules="module \"([a-z0-9_]+)\"\ \{"
modules=$(grep -Eh "$regex_modules" $terraform_files | sed -E "s/$regex/module.\1 /g")
```

ref:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter
- https://github.com/dflook/terraform-github-actions/tree/main/terraform-plan